# Creating an instant messaging application in Android

Tags: android

i am developing an instant messaging app same as Life360 for android. can anyone tell me how to send an invitation to a friend in contact list to install the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your application on play store or already hosted somewhere, just make a string that has the message you want to send with a link to play store or your apk.

This is code to display something like this

[image]

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

More information: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html